# Firebase JWT work for simple function but its not working when i want to use multiple function JWT authentication in Express js

Tags: javascript, jwt, token, express-jwt

I used React js library for the frontend and google firebase for authentication. In the backend, I use node js (Express Js). for user verification I used JWT verification. It works only with one API call. when I used another API but the API not working perfectly. should I make different functions for every API?

Comment: Hey Saif, currently there's too few details in the question and it will be hard for anyone to help you on that. Maybe you could provide some relevant code or configuration fragments. Also tell us how are you making those API calls. How are they different? Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to check what constitutes a good question on SO. You'll get better help and faster if you write your questions correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.